# lwc generating class 'homeDesktopTemplateHeaderThreeColumns' putting min-width css property

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, css, html, slds

```
<template>
<div class="listContainer">
  <template if:true={products.data}>
    <template for:each={products.data} for:item="product">
      <div key={product.Id}>
        <div class="card">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://static2.cilory.com/189111-thickbox_default/no-logo-royal-blue-full-sleeves-henley-t-shirt.jpg" alt="t-shirt">
          </figure>
          <section class="details">
            <div class="min-details">
              <h1>{product.Name} <span>{product.ProductCode} - {product.Description}</span></h1>
              <h1 class="price">$45.99</h1>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn">add to cart</a>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
</div >
```

```
.listContainer{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

}

Im facing this issue that salesforce is putting a parent element with a class called homeDesktopTemplateHeaderThreeColumns, This class is putting a CSS property 'min-width: 1050px' which is breaking my component on mobile.

[image]